# Can we have a listbox as a field in Gridview, and also can be make editable fields inside a Gridview..?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, gridview

I have to create a prescription for doctor, where medicines are automatically taken from database, and doctors can then write the type, potency and frequency of the medicine to be taken themselves.

So I want to retrieve medicines within a `Gridview`, inside a `Listbox` type field. Is this possible.

Secondly I also want that if a medicine is not present in the database, doctors can edit a `Listbox` to add it. Finally I want some directly editable fields like `Textboxes` for potency, frequency and type.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, you can do that. you just place a `TextBox` or `ListBox` or whatever control of your choice inside GridView. And you can initialize them with some value or, you can insert value in it.

All that you are required to is to find those controls inside the GridView, as it is a data-repeater control, so suppose you place one textbox inside the GridView, and you bound it with a List having 5 items, then 5 such textboxes will be rendered, so you need to be able to exactly locate your required textBox.

Below am giving you a super simple example.

your GridView markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="Review_grid" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="10" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" onrowdatabound="Review_grid_RowDataBound" 
            >
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ListBox">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ListBox ID="lstBox" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TextBox">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

your codebehind code.

```
///create datasource for your GridView.
public void BindGrid()
{
    DataTable db = new DataTable();
    db.Columns.Add("col1");
    db.Columns.Add("col2");
    db.Columns.Add("col3");
    db.Rows.Add("1", "2", "3");
    db.Rows.Add("1", "2", "3");
    db.Rows.Add("1", "2", "3");

    Review_grid.DataSource = db;
    Review_grid.DataBind();
}
```

trap controls in `RowDataBound` event of `GridView`, to initialize them with some value:

```
protected void Review_grid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                //find ListBox
                ListBox lst = (ListBox)e.Row.FindControl("lstBox");
                lst.Items.Add(new ListItem("item1"));
                lst.Items.Add(new ListItem("item2"));
                lst.Items.Add(new ListItem("item3"));

                //find textBox
                TextBox txt = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtBox");
                txt.Text = "test";

            }
        }
```

call the `BindGrid()` in `Page_load` of the page.

You need to explore more about [GridView](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/Category518-ASP.NET-GridView.aspx) and Other [dataControls](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/aspnet-data-controls).

Comment: Can we add any item into this created listbox,once the website has run, I means after it displays the page..??

Comment: why not?? ofcourse you can do that, there is no such specific event for a ListBox though, what you can do is, you can place a button beneath each of these listBox inside GridView. and upon click of that button, you can show a popup(a hidden div, which appears upon click). and in that you can take input for the name of the new item, and as you submit, again you iterate through the items of GridView, and FindControl your ListBox, and add the item (from the input in the div)..and save it to db, and repopulate your GridView